# Javascript : Filter list by last time of day and return a single value

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

I have a list of times of text messages and I am trying to return the last text message sent on a  particular day.

I am new to Javascript maybe this is easy but I just don't know how to do this
This what I have tried I am completely clueless.

**My Code:**

```
    const texts = [

    {
        date: "27 Jan 2021",
        text: "Hey nice to see you",
        time: "12:22",
    },
    {
        date: "27 Jan 2021",
        feeling: "Cry",
        text: "All good you?",
        time: "16:26",
    },
    {
        date: "27 Jan 2021",
        text: "You too how's life treating you?",
        time: "12:26",
    },


]

const output = texts.filter(i=>i.time)
```

**Desired Output:**

```
const output = [
    {
     date: "27 Jan 2021",
     feeling: "Cry",
     text: "All good you?",
     time: "16:26",
   },
]
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Maybe `let [output] = texts.sort((a, b) => b.time.localeCompare(a.time))` assuming the time property follows this format `->` `hh24:mm`

Answer (score 1):

Sorting and then taking first / last depending on how you sorted is a popular way, but it's not the most efficient if the array is very large.

But you could use reduce to keep the accumulator with the maximum value.

eg.

```js
const texts = [{"date":"27 Jan 2021","text":"Hey nice to see you","time":"12:22"},{"date":"27 Jan 2021","feeling":"Cry","text":"All good you?","time":"16:26"},{"date":"27 Jan 2021","text":"You too how's life treating you?","time":"12:26"}];
     
const result = texts.reduce((a, v) => {
  return v.time > a.time ? v : a;
});
 
console.log([result]);
```

> As noted in comments, make sure your times are zero prefixed, it's generally the case as it's the ISO standard, but worth checking just in case.

> If your times are not zero prefixed, as mentioned in comments, a simple solution would be to convert to minutes and compare with this.  Another option is to prefix with zero using `padLeft`

Comment: Furthermore, `.reduce()` is way better suited if you would need to check for `date` to equal ;some given value (considering OP might be looking to filter by particular date as well).

Comment: This will fail, if the AM hours are not stored with two digits, ex. when `time` is "9:26", it's larger than "16:26". OP didn't give any specific hour format, though.

Comment: @Teemu,  good point.  I always store times zero prefixed, and is the ISO standard so really should be the norm..

Comment: Simple parser (like `const [h, m] = v.time.split(':'), time = +m + 60*h`) may solve the issue.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov  Yes, that's another idea, convert to minutes and sort on that.  I'll keep the answer as it to keep it simple, but add a note to look in comments for none zero prefixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort and get the first element.

*This is assuming the `time` property follows this format `->` `hh24:mm` and the `date` property references to a specific day only.*

```js
const texts = [
  {
    date: "27 Jan 2021",
    text: "Hey nice to see you",
    time: "12:22",
  },
  {
    date: "27 Jan 2021",
    feeling: "Cry",
    text: "All good you?",
    time: "16:26",
  },
  {
    date: "27 Jan 2021",
    text: "You too how's life treating you?",
    time: "12:26",
  }
]

let [output] = texts.sort((a, b) => b.time.localeCompare(a.time));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you said "last text message sent on a particular day" I'd first filter for that date, then sort them and then get the last entry's text.

Something like:

```js
const texts = [
  {
    date: "27 Jan 2021",
    text: "Hey nice to see you",
    time: "12:22",
  },
  {
    date: "27 Jan 2021",
    feeling: "Cry",
    text: "All good you?",
    time: "16:26",
  },
  {
    date: "27 Jan 2021",
    text: "You too how's life treating you?",
    time: "12:26",
  },
]

const date = "27 Jan 2021";
const output = texts
  .filter(
    (text) => text.date = date
  ).sort(
    (textA, textB) => textA.time.localeCompare(textB.time)
  ).pop().text || 'No text found for this date';

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Sorting (O(n log(n)) time complexity) in addition to filter (O(n) time complexity) is way too expensive, where as single pass with `.reduce()` (O(n)) can solve both filtering and finding max time with a single pass.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this..

```js
  const texts = [
    {
        date: "27 Jan 2021",
        text: "Hey nice to see you",
        time: "12:22",
    },
    {
        date: "27 Jan 2021",
        feeling: "Cry",
        text: "All good you?",
        time: "16:26",
    },
    {
        date: "27 Jan 2021",
        text: "You too how's life treating you?",
        time: "12:26",
    }];

    var lastMsg = [];
    texts.forEach(element => {
        lastMsg = element
    });
    console.log(lastMsg);
```